# How to use returned Object of .getSingleResult() EntityManager

Tags: java, sql, jpa, entitymanager

I have the following SQL Statement and I used .getSingleResult() to get a Object from the EntityManager:
`SELECT sum(pos_netto) as revenue from Auftraege_Positionen_BI_Test where art_nr = :artNr`
I stored it in the Object returnObject. Now my Question is how can I get the value I selected via the SQL Statement out of the Object?

Answer (score 1):

Given your case
It seems like you want to take out the sum which most probably is a double value
You can simply use

```
double returningSum=(Double) query.getSingleResult();
```

Or to check if it is null and taking appropriate actions like assigning 0

```
Object result=(Object) query.getSingleResult();
double returningSum=result==null?0.0: (Double) result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnbvz/index.html) , `sum` returns Long or Double or BigInteger or BigDecimal etc value, so I think you don't need to do any conversion when using `query.getSingleResult()`.

Just check what is type of `pos_netto` field in your class & use that type directly as a return type of `query.getSingleResult()`.

Comment: I am pretty sure conversion is required in case it needs to be used as double rather than just an object

Comment: yeah, but if you do `query.getSingleResult().getClass().getCanonicalName()`, it must print something other than `Object` for sure. So that is reason I think conversion is not required. Though your answer is  also true.